# Django: where is the code that prints the "+" icon close to a foreign key?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-forms

I cannot find which part of code print the "+" that is close to every foreign key field.

In `fieldset.html` there is only the call to `{{ field.field }}`, but in the file  `django/forms/widgets.py` the code that prints the select, doesn't contain that code, so I suppose that there is a piece of code that manage the foreign key: where is it?

Thanks,
Giovanni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the admin interface, you should look for it in `django/contrib/admin/widgets.py`

The class name is `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`